# How to avoid injection for sorting query by runtime value

Tags: sql, security, orm, coldfusion

This is a common problem when the query allows you to sort a column by passed-in arguments. Below is what I am trying with ColdFusion ORM. I know that doing this will add a security loop-hole for SQL injection. Since ORDER BY cannot put on parameter we have to append it in the query itself. I have already escaped some vulnerable characters but still I cannot say that is safe (from SQL injection). ESAPI provides the function `encodeForSQL()` but this doesn't work SQL Server (it works with MYSQL though).

Another approach I normally use is that instead of passing a column name in the arguments, I pass some numeric value and use switch-case to match the proper column name... but this is an increase in maintenance.

Is there any good method for escaping sorting parameters in SQL (or HQL) when we cannot use named parameters?

```
<cfscript>
    var gridstruct = {};
    var isPaging = 0;
    var hql = "FROM tbl6 order by #arguments.sortcolumn#";      
    x = entitytoquery(ORMexecuteQuery(hql,false));
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `encodeForSQL()` "not working" for SQL Server?

Comment: @AdamCameron, You can find sample code at  https://gist.github.com/thecfguy/7784349. For encodeforsql you need to provide codec for database type and I am not able to find any codec for sql server. Codec available for Oracle and MySQL

Comment: Ah, I'm with ya. I thought CFML had a `encodeForSQL()` function built in (I just assumed it was added along with the rest of the `encodeFor*()` functions added in CF10. Reading up on it, it seems to be a frowned-up approach to SQL sanitising anyhow.

Comment: I guess this is why it wasn't added by ColdFusion with rest of the encodeFor*().:)

Comment: The Oracle Codec does not do more than to escape the single quote. That is an issue MSSQL would face, too, and can thus be mitigated using *OracleCodec* when handling SQL Server code. It does not prevent the issue with the start of a new command that is shown in the gist, mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably just validate the value of the incoming `sortcolumn` argument against a known list of values that are appropriate. SQLI aside, you'd not want to be sorting on just *any* column in the underlying schema, surely?

eg:

```
if (!isValid("regex", arguments.sortcolumn, "list|of|valid|values|here")){
    throw(type="IllegalArgumentException");
}
```

Comment: +1 to this. I normally use some numeric value to hide column name from user.

Comment: Although you might want a "user friendly" name displayed in URLs and such like, so you'd want to translate it anyways (essentially, the same as using a number) - after all, it's not like every language uses the same words, right?

Comment: Instead of a numeric value to 'hide' the column name, I typically will use a word that is user friendly, but is NOT the column name. I would add to this, you also will likely need to check for `asc` or `desc`, so while this response works, there will likely need to be a bit more logic involved.